# Spring boot @Autowired not working in unit test case

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, autowired

As I understand that if we use spring stereotypes then we don't need to use new keyword to create an instance. Spring manages that for us and provide us with the beans at runtime.

And in order for Spring to inject those beans we need to use `@Autowired` annotation where we want Spring to inject that bean.
Below I have a very simple class where I am using `@Component` so that spring manages that. This class has one List which I am initializing with my own responsibility and then a small method which does some logic.

```
@Slf4j
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class Parser {

    private List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void parseStrings(final String[] strs) {

        Arrays.stream(strs)
                .map(String::toLowerCase)
                .filter(str -> str.length() > 8)
                .filter(str -> str.endsWith("sam"))
                .forEach(sam1 ->  { strList.add(sam1); });
    }

}
```

I also wrote one unit test to test that and here is that.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class ParserTest {

   @Autowired
   private Parser parser;

    @Test
    void parseStrings() {
        String str[] = {"abcsamsam", "abcsyjhgfed abdul sam","abcAhgbkgdjhul samad", "abcabjhgdulsamsam", "sa"};
        parser.parseStrings(str);

        assertTrue(parser.getStrList().size() == 3);
        assertTrue(parser.getStrList().get(0).equalsIgnoreCase("abcsamsam"));

    }
}
```

The test fails with

`java.lang.NullPointerException` when it tries to call `parseStrings` method which means that its not able to inject a proper initialized bean at run time.

Can some one guide that what I am missing?
Is it necessary to add constructors (which here I am doing using lombok annotations) when using spring stereotypes on a class.

Comment: Instead of  @Autowired use `@InjectMocks` in unitTest and it should work. Also no need to add lombok annotations for Spring component. Lombok is used mainly in DTO or pain POJO

Comment: What's the package of class Parser? Did you add that package to the component scan? Do you have any test configuration class?

Comment: No, not added so do i need to add that to Unit test or to actual Parser class?

Comment: Try with the following annotation in your test: `@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Parser.class })`

Comment: @doctore it worked with the following
@ContextConfiguration(classes = LookupParser.class) along with SpringRunner and SpringBootTest annotations

Thanks. But what does this ContextConfiguration does?

Comment: Glad to help. That annotation tells Spring where are class it has to manage, so in that way you will be able to use `@Autowire` in your tests. However, there are better alternatives to use it in that way. For example, `@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)` and include in such class the required configuration for your tests. Like, the path of the all classes you are going to use in your different Junits/Integration tests, etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any mock created so why you are using `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`?

I've seen as well answers recommending the use of `@SpringBooTest`. This annotation loads the whole context of your application basically for integration tests in order to  integrate different layers of the application. That also means no mocking is involved. Do you really need that? (I don't think so since you're talking about unit test)

If your parser doesn't reference any other Bean (which need to be mocked), then you are in case of simple unit test.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) // you can even removed it 
class ParserTest {

private Parser parser;

@Before
public void setUp() {
     parser = new Parser();

}

    @Test
    void parseStrings() {
        String str[] = {"abcsamsam", "abcsyjhgfed abdul sam","abcAhgbkgdjhul samad", "abcabjhgdulsamsam", "sa"};
        parser.parseStrings(str);

        assertTrue(parser.getStrList().size() == 3);
        assertTrue(parser.getStrList().get(0).equalsIgnoreCase("abcsamsam"));

    }
```

Comment: How can we use Parser class without new method? Means something like @Autowire

Answer (score 1):

Spring `Autowire` if you run the test case with `SpringRunner`. So modify the test class as follows.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class ParserTest {

}
```

To answer your second question,
No, it is not necessary to add `no-argument constructor` unless you also have a `parameterised constructor` in the same class. In that case you need to explicitly add a no-arg constructor.

Comment: Still the same exception after adding 
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

Comment: Keep your application in running.

Comment: Why do i need to run my application if iam just trying to write a piece of code and just wanted to test it?

Comment: Spring will autowire beans from application context and stereotype beans will be added to context only if you run the application. If you don't want to run the application then inject the object yourself.

Comment: @Pradyskumar that is not true.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class ParserTest {

   @Autowired
   private Parser parser;

    @Test
    void parseStrings() {
        String str[] = {"abcsamsam", "abcsyjhgfed abdul sam","abcAhgbkgdjhul samad", "abcabjhgdulsamsam", "sa"};
        parser.parseStrings(str);

        assertTrue(parser.getStrList().size() == 3);
        assertTrue(parser.getStrList().get(0).equalsIgnoreCase("abcsamsam"));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why so you even need MockitoJUnitRunner here? The Parser has no dependencies. A simple initialization in the test will be enough. Just inialize the Parser instead of using an annotation. `@SpringBootTest` is meant for integration tests. It brings in the Spring context and makes your unit test slow & bulky.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the class was **not** declared **public**

Answer (score -3):

SpringBoot2,you can use the annotation:**@SpringBootTest** to do unit test.

just like below case:

```
@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {
   
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Comment: I am getting 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

if i do
@SpringBootTest
class ParserTest

Comment: @Dimple, Welcome to the SO :-). '@SpringBooTest' is recommended when doing integration test since it loads the whole context of the application. (or partially, if you specify some package to be scanned)